# Encoding Error in PHP Generated XML File

Tags: php, mysql, xml, utf-8

I have generated an XML file in PHP using the DOMDocument class, the data was grabbed from a MySQL database.  A lot of the data contains HTML markup, but I've encased all of it in a CDATA section.

At first the file had a lot of encoding errors, but running everything through utf8_encode() before putting it into the file seems to have fixed all the errors except one.

Here is the error I have right now:

```
    error on line 5113 at column 450: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
    Bytes: 0x14 0x31 0x30 0x30
```

I found some posts on here with similar errors, but none have solved my problem, or suggest using utf_encode().  Here is the section that seems to be triggering the error:

```
    ...quiet portable package. ]]></Summary><Features><![CDATA[The EF4500iSE was designed for maximum fuel...
```

The error seem to be between CDATA[ and The, although I can't see any characters between there and that piece is the same as every other CDATA block in the file.  If I remove the entire Features element and it's contents, the file loads up fine.

Here is the link to the file: http://test.hhdev.hothousemarketing.com/inventory.xml

Comment: In that particular CDATA tag, there seems to be a strange character between "rpm" and "1000". Have you tried `utf8_encode`?

Comment: Yes everything I am putting in is going through utf8_encode() first

Comment: Yeah removing the character you mentioned fixes it, now can get rid of it in PHP when the file is generated?

Comment: The brute force way would be to do a regex replacement of non-ASCII characters - though I personally don't like that solution. To be honest, it sort of depends on your application

Comment: You should remove the garbage character (byte `0x14`) from your source data. It has no business existing.  If you use `createTextNode()` instead of `createCDATASection()` you will at least be warned of these character when you *save* the document rather than when you parse it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a non-ASCII character present within the CDATA tag, as pointed out by Colin in the comments of the question.

I was in a rush to solve this so I just used a brute force method and ran everything through a regex replacement in addition to utf8_encode(), I used:
        $output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $output);
I found this here: http://www.stemkoski.com/php-remove-non-ascii-characters-from-a-string/

Thanks to Colin and Francis for their contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Some characters are just flat-out not permitted in XML, even in a CDATA section, even entity-encoded.

You might be able to use this on a UTF-8 string (untested):

```
$xml_legal_chars = preg_replace('/[\x{00}-\x{08}\x{0B}\x{0C}\x{0E}-\x{1F}\x{D800}-\x{DFFF}\x{FFFE}\x{FFFF}]/u', '', $utf8string);
```